# Application title bar disappeared - UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have na uwp app (published in Windows/Microsoft Store), and the app title bar is normally this:
[image]

I was doing some tests in my app (to test the fluent design system) and I made some changes and I did not notice, because now it appears like this:
[image]

The name of my app has disappeared and the ellipsis (...) that is included in the header of the page also does not appear.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you set TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true in your code? If so, remove that code to get the standard title bar back.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT I do not have this statement in my code :(

Comment: Are you using any library/nugget package that might be setting it? What happens if you set it to false from your code?

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT I'm just using Template10, but I've always used it and I did not have this problem. The strange thing is that I have already analyzed my code and can not find anything different that could cause this situation!

Comment: Check you Nuget packages, did any of them get updated recently? What happens if you set the property false? What happens when you create a new app, do you see the same? Without seeing your code we can only speculate.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT I did not update any Nuget packages. How do I set the property to false?
This is my app.xaml.cs: [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/366274df6e8cd68ed89a9cd1577b3b0b)

Comment: Since we don't know where your app is setting this to true, I can't answer this. For testing I would first add a button to set this to false to make sure it works, then narrow down further where to put it in your startup path. Again: does this repro for a new blank project? If not, then there is something in your project that is setting this. If you don't share it, we can only speculate.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT I really appreciate your help!
If I create a new project this problem does not happen, so this is some instruction I have in my code and I can not find it. The strangest thing is that I have already looked at all my code and and I can not find anything "strange" which causes it.
How do I set the property to false? `TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = false` Where and How?

Comment: I have shared a sample here to demonstrate how to set this property: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AovTwKUMywTNnOsbzlRfghOikDy8Dw

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT thank you! In this exemple, where is `TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = false` ?

Comment: Your search didn't find it? It's a very small example. The code is in MainPage.xaml.cs line 36.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT sorry but I dont find anything :(
Line 36 is empty!

Comment: It's line 37 actually :-)  - here is a direct link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AovTwKUMywTNnPI41WznhoDd8W0Nlg

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT thank you very much! This resolve my problem! This is really what I want!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happened to me too exactly when I was testing fluent design system!

To recreate the issue. Simply  Add

```
// Extend acrylic
extendAcrylicIntoTitleBar(); to OnLaunched at App.xamel.cs
```

Then add following code to App.xamel.cs

```
/// Extend acrylic into the title bar. 
private void extendAcrylicIntoTitleBar()
{
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = 
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
}
```

Next you need to fix the missing using by hitting Ctrl + . key.

At this point the title bar disappear. Even removing the extendAcrylicIntoTitleBar() function will not solve the issue!

The title bar will appear again if I remove following

```
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
```

I am not sure if it is a issue. That seems to be the way  fluent design works

Above test is done according to
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic#acrylic-theme-resources

Comment: Thank you very much! I simple put this code `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = false;` and fix the problem

Comment: By following what @FernandoSousa did I still had a wrong background colour for the 3 top right icons of the bar. I fixed it by uninstalling the app builtby visual studio and rebuilding it.

Comment: Once you set it to true it seems to stick in a setting somewhere and persist even after the application has ended.  Having to uninstall seems to support that theory at which point that setting would disappear.  I've just set it to false which also works (but doesn't seem like you should have to do that).

Answer (score 4):

The last value is cached in the registry. Try deleting this:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\<GUID_PublisherID>\PersistedTitleBarData\<GUID_PublisherID>!App]
"AppVersion"=hex(b):00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00
"ExtendViewIntoTitleBar"=dword:00000001
```

Also saved nearby is last window position, and splash screen info.

---

[image]

Comment: During debug and setting `ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = false` did not solve the problem. Thanks for your hint! 

Comment: This is absolutely terrible framework design. What in Heaven's name? Why is it "saved"? Isn't it supposed to be an app design choice by the developer? But thank you for the fix. I've been experimenting with Windows 11 app designs here and must have triggered this.